# How to import a postgis database in ubuntu (osgeo live 7)

Tags: postgis, database, osgeo

How does one import a postgis database in the ubuntu/osgeo live environment? In windows I would copy the backed up database file into the postgres bin folder and then use cmd to restore the databse. As I am new to the ubuntu/osge live environment I am not sure how to go about restoring a postgis database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would back the database up in the windows environment using the PGAdmin tool

Install PGAdmin then "Right click" the database, select "Backup" and choose custom format

Move this file to the ubuntu environment and the commands:-

```
createdb mydb
pg_restore -Fc -d mydb <filename>
```